# How do I set h and k so as to not be self-contradictory?

Tags: geometry

Got my final quiz back before the final exam. Had this really funky problem that I knew I messed up on, about translating an equation. I'd like to know how to get the solution, rather than the solution itself, if possible. Or, at least, the proper way to read it.

I'm thinking what I needed to do was to combine like terms and complete the squares before trying to plug in h and k. Anyway, here's the problem as presented.

> This equation can be written in the standard form of a conic section in a new set of translated coordinates $(x',y')$ where $x = x'+h$ and $y=y'+k$. Substituting the translation equations into the original equation yields,
>   $$(21 - 2k + 24h + 4h^2 + k^2) + (24+8h)x' + 4x'^2 + (-2+2k)y'+y^2 = 0$$
>   Choose an appropriate choice for $h$ and $k$ such that this equation is in the standard form of a conic section. Then determine the resulting equation in these translated coordinates.

The instructor basically said to always try and get $h$ and $k$ to equal 0, so I set the variables equal to 0, and worked from there. It eventually reduced to $((2x'+6)^2 / 13) + ((y'-1)/13) = 1$ , an ellipse. I (perhaps erroneously) reduced the x portion further to be $2(x'+3)^2 / 13$.

This doesn't make any sense. h and k are equal to 0, but we've still got a non-origin center. For some reason, however, he didn't mark that part as incorrect. He marked the "2" (in front of $(x+3)$), and the "/13" for both parts of the equation.

So, I'm wrong, but in the completely different way than I thought I was, so I'm completely and totally lost. Or maybe I am completely wrong, and he was just making random markings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard form I remember was $\left(\frac xa\right)^2 \pm \left(\frac yb\right)^2 =1$ where the plus sign is an ellipse and the minus sign a hyperbola.  To get that you have to choose $h,k$ to eliminate the linear terms.  You don't want $h,k=0$ you want the coefficients of $x',y'$ to be $0$.  That calls for $h=-3, k=1$

Comment: Ooo....That might be what is needed. Much appreciated.

Comment: Yeah. That was definitely it. Thanks a bunch.